# CLI: What is the difference between "setup:static-content:deploy" and "dev:source-theme:deploy"?

Tags: magento2, cli, setup-di-compile

I wanto to know the difference between:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

I know that second receives as options name of specific vendor, theme and language. And first one builds everything for all possible combinations of these options values. Am I right?

Are there any other differences in `images`, `JS`, `CSS` etc ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

command runs to create symlinks to LESS files

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-less-sass.html

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

command runs to create Static View Files (css, theme images, js) static view file refers to the following)
“Static” means

1. “Static” means it can be cached for a site (that is, the file is not dynamically generated). Examples include images and CSS generated from LESS.
2. “View” refers to presentation layer (from MVC).

: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Answer (score 0):

`setup:static-content:deploy` : Deploys static view files.

`dev:source-theme:deploy` : Collects and publishes source files for theme.

I suggest you to run this **command** to see the commands and their purpose !

```
php bin/magento
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ==> Deploys static view files

dev:source-theme:deploy ==>    Creates CSS from LESS
```